# Prove that integral $I_{p} = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^p\cos^2x}dx$ is convergent for $p < 3$

Tags: real-analysis

For $p \in \mathbb{R}$ we have integral $$I_{p} = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^p\cos^2x}dx$$

So I have to prove that this integral $I_{p}$ is convergent for $p < 3$

Any help how to start?

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor's series, you have around $0$

$$\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^p\cos^2x} \sim -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^{p-2}}$$ and
$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^q}$ converges if and only if $q<1$.

Comment: Is this the only way or is also another way to solve to this problem? I do not know how did you get this result using Taylor ' s series

Comment: I won't venture to say it is the only way! But at the end, *evaluating the size* of $\ln \cos x$ is a natural way. And Taylor's series are appropriate for that.